# data.table: using setkey with a column name variable

Tags: r, data.table

I have a variable name saved into the string variable `which_id`.

`W` is a data.table. How do I call `setkey` on `W` with `which_id` ?

This is what I've tried

```
 > eval( paste( 'setkey(W,' , which_id , ')' ) )
[1] "setkey(W, customer_id_A )"
```

But a call to `tables()` shows that the `customer_id_A` key didn't take.

```
 > evalq( paste( 'setkey(W,' , which_id , ')' ) )
[1] "setkey(W, customer_id_A )"
```

`customer_id_A` key still didn't take.

```
 > setkeyv( W , cols=which_id )
```

and

```
 > setkeyv( W , cols=c( which_id ) )
```

--> same thing, `customer_id_A` key isn't there.

Any pointers?

Comment: I don't think the fancy `eval` stuff will be needed. Your last try, with `setkeyv` should work, I think. Anyway, the way I usually do evals is with `eval(parse(text="..."))` whereas you are doing `eval("...")`.

Comment: The `parse` call did the trick, thanks. I was wondering if there was a 'data.table-native' way.

Comment: `setkeyv(W, which_id)` works for me, you may want to make your question reproducible - put in specific `W` and `which_id`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`setkeyv` should work.  Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(data.table)
W <- data.table(customer_id_A = 1:2)
which_id <- "customer_id_A"
setkeyv(W, which_id)
tables()
##      NAME NROW MB COLS          KEY          
## [1,] W       2 1  customer_id_A customer_id_A
## Total: 1MB
```